# Freeing a struct pointer, then setting it to null, then returning throws error

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have a remove node function in a binary search tree that looks like:

```
struct Node *_removeNode(struct Node *curr, TYPE val) {
    /* FIX ME */
    printf("curr->val: %.1f...%p\t val: %.1f\n", curr->val, curr, val);
    struct Node* to_del = NULL;

    if(val < curr->val){

            return _removeNode(curr->left, val);

    } else if( val > curr->val) {

            return _removeNode(curr->right, val);

    } else {

        //case 1 -> curr is a leaf
        if(curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL){
            printf("removed %.1f\n", curr->val);
            to_del = curr;
            free(to_del);

        }

        //case if left node is not null but right is
        if(curr->left != NULL && curr->right == NULL){
            to_del = curr;
            printf("to_del: %p...%.1f\t", to_del, to_del->val);
            curr = curr->left;
            printf("new curr: %p...%.1f\n", curr, curr->val);
            free(to_del);

        }

        //case if right node is not null but left is
        if(curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL){
            to_del = curr;
            printf("to_del: %p...%.1f\t", to_del, to_del->val);
            curr = curr->right;
            printf("new curr: %p...%.1f\n", curr, curr->val);
            free(to_del);
        }

        //case both are not not null
        if(curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL){
            to_del = curr;
            printf("to_del: %p...%.1f\t", to_del, to_del->val);
            curr->right->left = curr->left;
            curr = curr->right;
            printf("new curr: %p...%.1f\n", curr, curr->val);
            free(to_del);
        }


    }

    to_del = NULL;
    return to_del;

}
```

The code is supposed to return a pointer to NULL in order to pass the test cases, yet everything I try throws a memory error. Is there a way you can set a struct to NULL then return it?

Comment: Throws on **which line**?

Comment: Shouldn't `_removeNode` be checking if `curr` is NULL before doing anything with it? It just jumps right in and references `curr->val` before knowing if `curr` is a valid pointer.

Comment: For the `//case if left node is not null but right is` you probably want an `else if`, otherwise, if the previous if block ran you will have free'd `curr` and then dereference it as part of `curr->left`.  The same applies to the `//case if right node is not null but left is` if condition.

Comment: you realize that if val  isn't equal to `curr->val` that you're possibly calling the same function over and over again? Run your code through a debugger and see whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
    if(curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL){
        to_del = curr;
        free(to_del);
    }
    if(curr->left != NULL && curr->right == NULL){
```

If the first `if` is true, then the memory pointed to by `curr` will be released. When you then do in the second if `curr->left`, then you get an error because there is no `->left` anymore.

Maybe you should use `else if`?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It worked out pretty well after I did that.